# How to gradually shift current Django unit tests to pytest?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

Currently, I have a Django 1.11 project. It's setup to act solely as an API backend using Django Rest Framework.

I write unit tests using mostly APITestCase from rest_framework.test, TestCase from django.test, and sometimes TestCase from test_plus.

When I execute my tests I typically use commands like

`python manage.py test`

`python manage.py test somemodule.tests.some_test_file.TestClass.specific_test_case`

Or the above but with the `keepdb` flag to shorten the testing time

`python manage.py test --keepdb`

`python manage.py test somemodule.tests.some_test_file.TestClass.specific_test_case --keepdb`

How do I shift to using pytest gradually?

By gradually, I mean long term I move to pytest and pytest commands, but in the meantime, the tests already written can still be used in a single commmand because my CICD on CircleCI is still dependent on the tests to pass.

I also use factory-boy if that's relevant.

Comment: Install `pytest-django`, then try running `pytest --ds=your.test.settings`. If you've did everything right when writing the test suite, it should execute right away. Once it works, move the option to `pytest.ini` so you don't have to specify it each time. `--keepdb` becomes `--reuse-db`, and passing the tests by name changes only a bit - your above example should become `pytest somemodule/tests/some_test_file.py::TestClass::specific_test_case`. Run `pytest --collect-only -q` to list all the test names `pytest` finds in your project; these can be passed as specific arguments.

Comment: Of course, grouping tests should also work, e.g. `pytest somemodule/tests/some_test_file.py` or `pytest somemodule/tests/some_test_file.py::TestClass` or globbing via `-k`, e.g. `pytest -k "TestClass*"` etc.